# Label encoding, one_hot encoding to labels

Tags: python, keras

My use case is about application of machine learning in wireless communication in a physical layer. 
My input features are complex valued, and I converted it into equivalent real valued features as follows.

```
 Y = np.concatenate((np.real(S_bar), np.imag(S_bar)))
Y = array([[-1.,  1.,  3.,  1., -3.,  1., -3., -3.,  1., -1.],
     [-1.,  3.,  3., -1.,  1.,  3., -3.,  1., -1.,  3.],
     [ 1., -1.,  3.,  3.,  3., -3., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
     [ 3.,  1., -3.,  3., -3.,  1.,  1.,  3.,  3., -1.]])
```

Y is a 4 x 10 training matrix with the 4 rows are features, and the 10 columns are samples or training examples. 
I want to represent this as one_hot encoded training labels of 10 x 4 to fit it in to keras environment like this:

```
      model.fit(X_train, Y_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=100)
```

I tried it the following way and it does't work.

i.  Label encoding:

```
     le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
     y = []
for i in range(0,Y.shape[0]):
    le.fit(Y[i,:])
   temp = le.transform(Y[i,:]) 
   y.append(temp)
y = np.array(y)
```

Y became Labeled:

```
 array([[1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1],
   [1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3],
   [2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [3, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

ii. one_hot encoding:

```
encoder=OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
encoder.fit(y.T)
labels = encoder.transform( y.T)
```

* My problem is,the 'labels' came out with a shape of (10,16) while the model is expecting (10,4). How to fit the size of the one_hot encoder to the true shape of Y_train and Y_test please ? or is there any other way better than this to do it with the above sample. I really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Can you provide your model output? Why is it expecting (10,4)?

Comment: Okay, here is what I did: I set the Y_train  to be the labels from the above. This is the the output layer: `model.add(Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))` `model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])`
`model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=1)` . And the output error is _ValueError_ : _Error when checking target: expected dense_9 to have shape (4,) but got array with shape (16,)_

Answer (score 0):

I would use `keras.utils.to_categorical` to get what you are after:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
labels = to_categorical(y[0])
# labels.shape == (10, 4)
```

which basically one-hot encodes the target labels for you.

Comment: thank you for your support, but in this case `labels = to_categorical(y[0])` can only pick the first class with 10 examples. We are missing the remaining three classes if we feed `to_categorical(y[0])` as a `Y_train`. y contains coded labels of  `(4 classes, 10 examples)` . I think I didn't understand something. My input data is numerical so not  one_hot encoded. `X_tain` is with a shape of `(10,100)` in this case. 10 examples, 100 features. At the output I want to classify into 4 classes. so I should have `(10,4) ` labels right ?